# PHP template syntax - is this correct?

Tags: php, mysql, templates, templating, templating-engine

I'm creating a website that's template-driven, but not using PHP template packages like Smarty or Twig, it's entirely my own coding.

This is one template (mypage.php): (moved to fit in on page)

```
<TITLE>{$title}</TITLE>
<TABLE>
<TR><TD>{$maker}</TD><TD>{$model}</TD><TD>{$trim}</TD><TD>{$body}</TD>
<TD>{$price}</TD>
</TABLE>
```

The content comes from a MySQL database, like this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mylogin", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test12") or die(mysql_error());
$query  = "SELECT name, subject, message FROM contact";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<table><td>{$row['maker']} <br><TD>{$row['model']}</TD><TD>{$row['trim']}</TD><TD>{$row['price']}</TD>" .
```

}

I think I've done it right, but if I've gone wrong let me know... it's my first proper go at it! (Edited to fit on to stackoverflow.com)

cheers

Comment: Which template? You don't have any template in your question you've written, you just said you want to use PHP. Maybe you're looking for [curly braces in strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (scroll down to *Variable parsing*)?

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I see is that you have not escaped the values you retrieve from the database.
This leaves you open to XSS.

I'd change the echo portion into:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $maker = htmlspecialchars($row['maker']);
  $model = htmlspecialchars($row['model']);
  $trim = htmlspecialchars($row['trim']);
  $price = htmlspecialchars($row['price']);

  echo "<table><td>{$maker}<br><TD>{$model}</TD><TD>{$trim}</TD><TD>{$price}</TD>".
}
```

Comment: @saltwynd I'm not a php-template wizard, so cannot help you there.